# Creating text boxes on client side on runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, client-side, server-side

I have a drop down list and it has values through 2 to 12. Two text boxes are being displayed. What I want is when user change the dropdown's value, text boxes should  be generated according to the count.

Should I do this on server side? I think it would be more better if done on client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery and this code:

```
var count = $('#dropDown').val();
for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
   $('#textboxContainer').append("<input type='text' />");
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution, but you might need to consider postbacks, and rendering of these dynamic elements. Give them ids that you can iterate through to rebind, if required?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=0;i<selectedValue;i++){
   var txt = document.createElement("input");
   txt.type = 'text';
   txt.id = "textbox_'+ i;
   document.getElementById('divId').append(txt);
}
```

If you want using JS.

Similar implementation you can do on asp.net, if you want from server side.

Answer (score 0):

No, this have to be done client side with javascript. jQuery simplyfies that really much.

Here is the code that does what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/mwSGB/2/